# Why is the hat leaderboard a little off?

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I have seen the hat leaderboard, and here's how it looks like:
1. Alecxe, a member for 7 years, 7 months, 29 hats
1. eLRuLL, a member for 7 years, 5 months, 29 hats
3. Eran, a member for 6 years, 10 months, 28 hats

As you can see, Eran got 3rd, instead of 2nd place. Is there a logical reason for this?

Comment: Hi Cursor! We got the same question, under a different title, yesterday. You'll find your answer there :)

Comment: ok, thanks! Should I delete this question?

Comment: As far as I know, duplicates are useful. People can find this one and then follow the trail, without having to know the exact search terms that will turn up the other question, so they can still find what they're looking for. So if it's up to me, it's not necessary...